# Search only blog posts (default WP search widget)

Tags: search

I was using this code:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','search_only_blog_posts' );

function search_only_blog_posts( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_search ) {

        $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

---

..until I realized that it applies to pretty much any default search in WordPress *(including search in post list page in admin area etc)*.

**How could I make the search widget to only search blog posts** *(not custom posts, taxonomies, images etc)* **so that it doesn't apply to any default WP search** *(only widget search)* **?**

Or is it easier to just make my own search widget?

I would prefer to utilize everything WordPress has to offer and not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@PieterGoosen has a good description on why your `pre_get_posts` callback is giving you a problem.

Here's an alternative workaround to restrict the native *search widget* to the *post* post type:

```
/**
 * Restrict native search widgets to the 'post' post type
 */
add_filter( 'widget_title', function( $title, $instance, $id_base )
{
    // Target the search base
    if( 'search' === $id_base )
        add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'wpse_post_type_restriction' );
    return $title;
}, 10, 3 );

function wpse_post_type_restriction( $html )
{
    // Only run once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Inject hidden post_type value
    return str_replace( 
        '</form>', 
        '<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" /></form>',
        $html 
    );
}
```

where we use adjust the output of the `get_search_form()` function but only for the search widgets.

Comment: Quite an unorthodox method to use the `widget_title` filter ;-)

Comment: yes, it comes in handy here, the `widget_display_callback` filter was another possibility  ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: Thanks for that info, never too old or too ugly to learn something ;-)

Comment: Both are very good answers but I tend to go with shorter one that utilizes the WordPress search itself. @PieterGoosen, doesn't `WP_Widget` give deprecated error? I haven't found alternative online _(did just few quick searches, not on top of my priority list right now)_.

Comment: @N00b No, I think you confuses it with the depreciated PHP4 type constructors. As I said, my code comes from core itself, just changed the names accordingly ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Ah, that explains a lot, it seems I didn't fully understand the deprecated error.. Thanks anyway. I can use your answer to fix my widgets. Two birds with one stone, bang!

Answer (score 4):

Your use of `pre_get_posts` is completely wrong.

- `pre_get_posts` is an action, not a filter. Check the [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L2480)

  ```
  do_action_ref_array( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this ) );
  ```

  Yes, `add_filter` works because `add_action` calls `add_filter`, that is why your code will work. But as for proper usage, it is just plain wrong. If something is an action, use `add_action()`. It just makes sense
- `WP_Query::is_search` (*and `WP_Query::is_search()` for that matter*) returns true on **any** query where `s` is passed to `WP_Query`. Remember, the conditional tags inside `WP_Query` are not set according to the URL, but according to the query vars passed to it. For the main query, the query vars passed to `WP_Query` will come from parsing the URL.
- `pre_get_posts` alters all instances of `WP_Query`, `query_posts` and `get_posts`, front end and back end regardless, so you would want to target only the main query if you only would want to target the main query. Additionally, you would only want to target the front end, specially for archives and search queries.

Here is an example on how to use `pre_get_posts` correctly for the main query: (*You can change the closure to normal spaghetti if you wish, just a note, only use closures if you're sure you would not want to remove the action later as anonymous functions can't be removed*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin()         // Only target front end,
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
         && $q->is_search()     // Only target the search page
    ) {
        $q->set( 'post_type', ['my_custom_post_type', 'post'] );
    }
});
```

To answer your question about the search widget, here is what I have found

- The [search widget](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-search.php) simply call [`get_search_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/)
- There is no useful filter to specifically target the search widget. The filters available in `get_search_form()` will target all forms which uses `get_search_form()`

With the above, you would need to create your own search widget with your own custom form

You can try the following: (*Modified from the core search widget, note, everything is untested*)

```
class My_Custom_Search extends WP_Widget {
    /**
     * Sets up a new Search widget instance.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = [
            'classname'   => 'widget_custom_search', 
            'description' => __( "A custom search form for your site.")
        ];
        parent::__construct( 'custom-search', _x( 'Custom search', 'My custom search widget' ), $widget_ops );
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the content for the current Search widget instance.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $args     Display arguments including 'before_title', 'after_title',
     *                        'before_widget', and 'after_widget'.
     * @param array $instance Settings for the current Search widget instance.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( $title ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }

        $form = '<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">
            <label>
                <span class="screen-reader-text">' . _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) . '</span>
                <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="' . esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder' ) . '" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" title="' . esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) . '" />
            </label>
            <input type="hidden" value="post" name="post_type" id="post_type" />
            <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="'. esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) .'" />
        </form>';

        echo $form;

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the settings form for the Search widget.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $instance Current settings.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, ['title' => '')];
        $title = $instance['title'];
        ?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" /></label></p>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Handles updating settings for the current Search widget instance.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $new_instance New settings for this instance as input by the user via
     *                            WP_Widget::form().
     * @param array $old_instance Old settings for this instance.
     * @return array Updated settings.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $new_instance = wp_parse_args((array) $new_instance, ['title' => '')];
        $instance['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] );
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put this in your functions.php file.

```
function SearchFilter($query) 
{
    if (($query->is_search)&&(!is_admin())) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Just Write this code on your functions.php WordPress theme.

```
function wpdocs_my_search_form( $form ) {
$form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
<div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __( 'Search for:' ) . '</label>
<input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="hidden" value="post" name="post_type" id="post_type" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__( 'Search' ) .'" />
</div>
</form>';

return $form;
} add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'wpdocs_my_search_form' );
```

Comment: Please explain why this helps … in an edit. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Please Refer this code and  setting [following link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-exclude-pages-from-wordpress-search-results/)

Comment: Please post a real answer, not a link to some page where someone might find a solution

Comment: Furthermore this is what the author already has, it won´t help him with anything...