# Some nav-menu filters do nothing

Tags: plugin-development, menus, filters

So, I've been trying to write a plugin, and I need to use the `'nav_menu_link_attributes'` filter. I tried adding the filter, but it didn't respond - at all. That is, I made it die mid-process once the filter was called.

```
...
# in class definition

public function __construct() {
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects',array($this,'filter_menuitem'));
}

public function filter_menuitem($attrs) {
    die('SUCCESS!!!');
}

...
```

I looked at the source for `nav-menu-template.php` to see what filters were called for what, and when. So, I tried using the following filters, one at a time, in the order they appear in the source; some worked, some didn't respond at all:

```
function wp_nav_menu() {
  wp_nav_menu_args                   Responded
  pre_wp_nav_menu                    Responded
  wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags  Did not respond - not a surprise
  wp_nav_menu_objects                Did not respond - should definitely have responded
  wp_nav_menu_items                  Did not respond - should definitely have responded
  wp_nav_menu                        Did not respond - should definitely have responded
}
```

The only catch that would've made sense was that the `'pre_wp_nav_menu'` can be used to generate a custom menu, skipping the WP default method which calls the following filters. But I tried using 3 different themes, and wouldn't expect that to be the case often, or even ever.

Am I missing something? Is this a WordPress bug? Is custom menu generation really that common?

**Details:**
WordPress 4.4.2
Tested Themes: Elegant Themes Divi 2.4.6.1, Twenty Thirteen, Twenty Fifteen
Plugins: Only my own, none of which use the `'pre_wp_nav_menu'` filter

**ANSWER:**
So, on *@Pieter Goosen's* answer, I looked in the source of the `wp_nav_menu` function, and found the `'wp_page_menu'` filter which is called on the full HTML code (no newlines; includes wrappers) once it's composed. For the context of what I'm doing it's sufficient, and after hooking and testing it, I found it works!

I also found the `'wp_list_pages'` filter works as well. Instead of the full HTML with all the tags, it only lists the `<li>` tags separated by newlines. No wrappers are included, not even the `<ul>` tag. I am skeptical, however, as to what else might be using this function. It may not be invoked only for the menu. Thus, to be safe, it might be better to stick with the `'wp_page_menu'` filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the `fallback_cb` argument in `wp_nav_menu()`. Most nav menus do not set this parameter, so the default value is used, which is `wp_page_menu`.

If you look at the source code of [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/), with no `fallback_cb` set (*defualt `wp_page_menu`*), you will see the following lines of code executes

```
if ( ( !$menu || is_wp_error($menu) || ( isset($menu_items) && empty($menu_items) && !$args->theme_location ) )
    && isset( $args->fallback_cb ) && $args->fallback_cb && is_callable( $args->fallback_cb ) )
        return call_user_func( $args->fallback_cb, (array) $args );
```

This code bails out and loads [`wp_page_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_page_menu/). This code executes after the `pre_wp_nav_menu` filter, that is why you see this filter executes. All filters after that few lines will not executes because `wp_nav_menu()` has now loaded `wp_page_menu()`.

If you now test the filters inside `wp_page_menu()`, you will see that they fire as expected.

You can have a look at [my answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/219293/31545) to see how I have used this to determine which filter to use

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy. ;-)